# Json on .net server for android

Tags: android, json

i have json for login interface and i got no ideas how to handle this type of json
please help me for how to handle this json

{
    "ActionVerb": "xyz",
    "Source": "android",
    "DTOCollect": [
        {
            "DTOoJson": {
                "LoginIdStr": "xyz",
                "UserPassStr": "xyz"
            },
            "DTOType": "loginRequestObj"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 1):

By "handle this type of json", I am guessing that you are asking how to deserialize this in java?

If so, the easiest way to go is to use a JSON library, there are quite alot of these. Personally I like [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), but google around for it and make your own selection